# Facebook Login Android keeps crashing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have been constructing a Facebook login for my android app. For some reason it keeps on crashing. I have followed this tutorial to the letter, and copied whole parts of this guys code (besides the part for copying photos, I removed anything picasso related and the xml elements belonging to it. I have also removed the textview with the user name.):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPG7Rxj3u94
https://github.com/delaroy/AndroidFacebook/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tutorialsbuzz/androidfacebook/LoginFragment.java

I have already checked my manifest, my gradle.build files to ensure i have the right dependencies. I have checked my app ID at facebook, and have input the ssl key. Lastly I have indeed initialized the FacebookSDK before trying to inflate any xml in the loginactivity.

at the moment I don't know what the error is...

Here is my error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.riaan.dutchmanners, PID: 25681
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.riaan.dutchmanners/com.example.riaan.dutchmanners.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                    at com.example.riaan.dutchmanners.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:26)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.example.riaan.dutchmanners.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:26) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                                 Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
                                                                                    at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:145)
                                                                                    at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.<init>(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
                                                                                    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.<init>(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                                                    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                                                    at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:69)
                                                                                    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:201)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.example.riaan.dutchmanners.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:26) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

If you need anything else besides this let me know!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your error says something important "The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first."

Comment: I have already done that! Still keeps crashing.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuilding.

Comment: Make sure to initialize Facebook sdk before inflating layout

Comment: The cleaning and rebuilding thing worked! Could you explain to me why?